# setting gesture/swipe to false is not working [react-navigation v5 ]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

In my react-native application, I want the drawer to be disabled on some screens. All the screens are Stack and passed to `drawerNavigation`. [Specifying `navigationOptions` for these two screens](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#specifying-navigationoptions-for-a-screen) with `gestureEnabled` or `swipeEnabled` to `false`, still by swiping the drawer opens

```
const StackScreens = ({navigation}) => (
  <Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName="SplashScreenCtrl"
    headerMode="screen"
    screenOptions={{}}
    mode="card">
    <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreenCtrl} options={{gestureEnabled: false}}/> // or swipeEnabled:false
    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{gestureEnabled: false}}/>
  {/* and 10 more screens*/}
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

// and in the render method
return (
    <StatusBar backgroundColor="black" barStyle="light-content" />
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawer {...props} />} >
        <Drawer.Screen name="DrawerScreen" component={StackScreens} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
);
```

Also defining the navigation options on screen does not work
Like;

```
// in LoginScreen.js
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    headerShown: false,
    swipeEnabled: false,
  });
// Then at creating stack navigator
<Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={LoginScreen.navigationOptions}/>
```

Answer (score -2):

Its late ,, but it may help some one

You should place the   gestureEnabled: false in your  Drawer declaration

```
   <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawer {...props} />} >
        <Drawer.Screen name="DrawerScreen" component={StackScreens} 
           options={{ gestureEnabled: false }}/>
```

Comment: This is a wrong answer. This will disable swipe for all the screens, not for some specific ones